# How to open recently modified or recently created file using command prompt bat file

Tags: batch-file

How to open recently modified or recently created file using command prompt bat file. I have a folder in my C: drive named "test plans" in which reports get save automatically (with name 'Summary141013 113403.csv'; "Summary" is a constant but date and time keep change). I want my .bat file to open recently created file.

Answer (score 0):

openLastFile.cmd

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
set _dir=c:\test plans
set _lastFile=
for /F "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /od /b "%_dir%\*.csv"') do set _lastFile=%%f
if not "%_lastFile%"=="" (
    notepad "%_dir%\%_lastFile%"
)
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /od "c:\test plans\*.csv"') do set "RecentFile=%%~a"
"c:\test plans\%RecentFile%"
```

This opens the file with the associated program.

Answer (score 0):

This will open files modified today in the Current Working Directory by NotePad:

```
FORFILES /M *.csv /D 0 /C "cmd /c notepad.exe @file"
```

Or open it with default associated open handler, MS Excel, eg:

```
FORFILES /M *.csv /D 0 /C "cmd /c @file"
```