# Open file using .bat which has a variable in name, most recent created only

Tags: batch-file, csv

I want to open the most recent .csv file in my "My Docs" directory that has a file name with a variable, so:  `"E:\My Documents\name 20140731.csv"`.  This is to open in excel.

The name will always be constant, however the last number will always differ (20140731, 20140814 etc).

I have a number of other files that open from within the same bat.

```
start "" Chrome --profile-directory="Profile 1" "https://mail.google.com/"   "https://stackoverflow.com/users/2337102/mrsadmin"
start "" Excel "E:\My Business\master.xlsm"
start "" Excel "E:\My Business\test.xlsm"
start "" Excel "E:\My Business\reconciled 20131031.xlsx"
start "" Excel "E:\My Documents\dev.xlsx"
start "" Explorer "E:\My Business\Accounts"
start "" "D:\Programs\2 Admin\MySQL Workbench\MySQLWorkbench.exe"
start "" Notepad "E:\My Business\info.txt
```

I have tried adding (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19357651/2337102)):

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /od "E:\My Documents\name*.csv"') do set "RecentFile=%%~a"
"E:\My Documents\%RecentFile%"

pause
```

However that doesn't work, I get error messages about the file not existing.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (
    'dir /b /a-d /od "E:\My Documents\name*.csv"'
) do set "RecentFile=%%~a"

start "" "E:\My Documents\%RecentFile%"
```

As the file contains spaces, the `for /f` is tokenizing the string and returning the first token, that is, the string `name`. Disabling the delimiters (setting `delims` to an empty list) avoids it